# Enumerator type versus compatible type

Tags: c, enums, language-lawyer

According to the draft C11 Standard [N1539](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1539.pdf), an `enum` in C has the following semantics (edited for brevity)

> **Semantics**
>
> 3 The identifiers in an enumerator list are declared as
>   constants that have **type int** and may appear wherever such are
>   permitted. [...]
>
> 4 Each enumerated type shall be compatible
>   with char, a signed integer type, or an unsigned integer type. The
>   choice of **type is implementation-defined**, but shall be capable of
>   representing the values of all the members of the enumeration. [...]
>
> C11 §6.7.2.2 3-4

**Questions**: if all the individual enumerators are constants of type int, why can the compatible type of the `enum` as a whole be an implementation-defined type? Why don't the enumerators have the same compatible type?

Comment: Because: stupid. This is a known flaw in the language. I suppose the rationale is that it would allow compilers to pick smaller types in case the enumeration constants are all value < 256, in order to save memory. But the compiler can do such optimizations anyhow, as long as the program behavior isn't affected. So in the end, this is just a defect in the language.

Comment: @Lundin but does the enumerator type (int) play any role when doing e.g. signed/unsigned comparisons? Suppose the compatible type of an enum is unsigned, and I want to compare some enumerator to an unsigned int variable?

Comment: @Lundin say I have `enum E { a = 0, b = 255 };` and the compiler uses `unsigned char` as compatible type, then which type is being used when doing comparisons? The `int` or the `unsigned char`?

Comment: If you use an enum variable in an expression, the implementation-defined type will be used. If you use an enum constant, `int` will be used. I.e. to use the example `enum { a = 0, b = 255 } e;` then `if(something == e)` will use implementation-defined type and `if(something == a)` will use `int` type. Yes, it is retarded, doesn't make sense and will cause all manner of dangerous implicit integer conversion bugs.

Comment: @Lundin OK, I'll accept if you write it as an anwer.

Comment: I don't really know the reason why they made it like this though, which is what you are asking :) Checking the C rationale, it only says: (6.4.4.3 Enumeration constants) "Whereas an enumeration variable may have any integer type that correctly represents all its values when widened to int, an enumeration constant is only usable as the value of an expression. Hence its type is simply int." So perhaps it is just a side effect of another defect in the C language: the implicit integer promotions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding on [@Lundin comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34221138/enumerator-type-versus-compatible-type#comment56186966_34221138), this approach is **consistent** with C constants like `'A'` having type `int` rather than `char`.

In C, there really are no raw constants of type smaller than `int`.  C favors promoting smaller types to `int` when possible.  I suspect it made for a simpler  compiler - something important in 1970s.

By allowing an instance of `enum` to be smaller, it takes up less space, much like a `char` may be smaller than `int`, as is usual.

```
int main(void) {
  char ch = 'A';
  enum EN {
    EN_a = 0, EN_b = 1
  };
  enum EN en;

  printf("sizeof (int):%zu\n", sizeof(int));
  printf("sizeof ch   :%zu (1 - by definition)\n", sizeof ch);
  printf("sizeof 'A'  :%zu (same as sizeof (int))\n", sizeof('A'));
  printf("sizeof en   :%zu (implementation defined)\n", sizeof en);
  printf("sizeof EN_a :%zu (same as sizeof (int))\n", sizeof EN_a);
}
```

Sample output

```
sizeof (int):4
sizeof ch   :1 (1 - by definition)
sizeof 'A'  :4 (same as sizeof (int))
sizeof en   :4 (implementation defined)
sizeof EN_a :4 (same as sizeof (int))
```

Not commenting as to is this is a good design - just explaining my understanding of why.

Comment: Note: with `<stdbool.h>`, `true, false` are both of type `int`.  The result of `a==b` is also type `int`.

Comment: @GhaziXG `()` are _not_ needed with `sizeof object`.